# How to extend selection in gnome-terminal? Depends on version?

Tags: terminal, gnome, gnome-terminal, selection

I just moved this question I made some time ago, from StackOverflow to here:

***In a terminal I can select a single line, double clicking with the Left Mouse Button.
With xterm, I can extend that selection clicking with the Right Mouse Button in the place I want to extend it.***

***Then can I paste the whole selection with the Middle Mouse Button or paste it in other application.***

***In gnome-terminal, it seems I can extend the selection clicking with the Left Mouse Button, but holding at the same time the Shift key.***

***Visually, it seems the selection is done, but when clicking with the Middle Mouse button or pasting in other application, I only get the primary single line selection.***

***How can I get the whole selection under gnome-terminal?***
***Is it possible to use selections in gnome-terminal as xterm does?***
***Cheers, Tomas.***

In Ubuntu with GNOME Terminal 2.30.2, it didn't not to work.
But I just tried it in CentOS with Gnome gnome-terminal 2.16.0, and it works.

Does it seems to be a matter of the gnome-terminal version?
Or is there some obscure issues related to XWindows copy&paste mechanisms?

Comment: Instead of cross-posting the question, maybe it would have been better to try to get the question migrated from StackOverflow to Superuser.  Cross-posting a question is generally discouraged.

Comment: As long as nobody contributed with an answer, I just deleted it from StackOverflow.